# Entity Framework Seeding is not creating data

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I can perform EF migration successfully. My table can be created but no seed data. I tried a few methods to seed data for Entity Framework 6 but no avail.

```
public class EmployeeDBContextSeeder :
       DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<EmployeeDBContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(EmployeeDBContext context)
    {
        List<Employee> EmployeeList = new List<Employee>()
        {
            new Employee() { FirstName = "Mark" },
            new Employee() { FirstName = "Ben" },
            new Employee() { FirstName = "John" }
        };

        context.Employees.AddRange(EmployeeList);
        context.SaveChanges();
        //  base.Seed(context);
    }
}

public class EmployeeDBContext : DbContext
{
    public EmployeeDBContext() : base("DB")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<EmployeeDBContext>(new EmployeeDBContextSeeder());
    }

    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

And I am not sure what is the difference between these two     `context.SaveChanges();` vs `base.Seed(context);`

I tried to move `Database.SetInitializer<EmployeeDBContext>(new EmployeeDBContextSeeder());` to global.asax Application_Start() but still unable to seed the data to my table.

For the migration command, I use `enable-migrations`, `Add-Migration Initial` and `Update-database`

Answer (score 1):

I am setting the initializer like this:
In your `DbContext`:

```
public static void Initialize()
{
   Database.SetInitializer( new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyContext, MyConfiguration>() );
}
```

And in the migrations folder there is the configuration class:

```
public sealed class MyConfiguration : 
   DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyContext>
{
   public Configuration()
   {
      AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
   }

   protected override void Seed( MyContext context )
   {
      //insert statements here
   }
}
```

And it works :-)

Comment: Where you define `Initialize()`?

Comment: Sorry, that is part of the class derived from DbContext

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to leave the call for `base.Seed(context)` uncommented.

Comment: I did it but still the same

Answer (score 0):

Do the following

```
public class SchoolDBInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<SchoolDBContext>
 {
  protected override void Seed(SchoolDBContext context)
  {
      IList<Standard> defaultStandards = new List<Standard>();

    defaultStandards.Add(new Standard() { StandardName = "Standard 1", Description = 
    "First Standard" });
    defaultStandards.Add(new Standard() { StandardName = "Standard 2", Description = 
    "Second Standard" });
    defaultStandards.Add(new Standard() { StandardName = "Standard 3", Description = 
    "Third Standard" });

    context.Standards.AddRange(defaultStandards);

    base.Seed(context);
    }
 }
```

Now, set this DB initializer class in context class as below.

```
  public class SchoolContext: DbContext 
  {
    public SchoolContext(): base("SchoolDB") 
    {
       Database.SetInitializer(new SchoolDBInitializer());
    }

    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Standard> Standards { get; set; }
  }
```